# ESP8266-01 wdt reset after uploading code

Tags: esp8266, web-server

I'm using code from here: [ESP8266 example: Wi-Fi Access point, static IP, web-server and remote GPIO control](https://42bots.com/tutorials/esp8266-example-wi-fi-access-point-web-server-static-ip-remote-control/).

Everything running ok this morning, but now I don't know why wasn't working...

This is what serial monitor display:

```
Configuring access point...
AP IP address: 42.42.42.42
HTTP server started

Exception (0):
epc1=0x40226744 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000000 depc=0x00000000

ctx: sys 
sp: 3fffed10 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 01a0

>>>stack>>>
3fffeeb0:  00000000 3fffdad0 3ffeefec 00000030  
3fffeec0:  3ffe9560 40226dbb 3fff0104 0000d158  
3fffeed0:  00000000 40216ec8 3ffedfe8 4020f68c  
3fffeee0:  00f20e64 3ffe9374 3ffe9204 3ffef190  
3fffeef0:  4020f7c8 3ffef194 3ffe91fc 60000600  
3fffef00:  40226731 3ffe9370 3ffee820 00000001  
3fffef10:  40226814 3ffe9374 3ffee820 0331cfa4  
3fffef20:  3fff0104 40100ab6 00000001 00000000  
3fffef30:  4022df51 40100883 00000000 00000000  
3fffef40:  4022df96 3fffdab0 00000000 3fffdcb0  
3fffef50:  3ffee838 3fffdad0 3ffeefec 402073e3  
3fffef60:  40000f49 40000f49 3fffdab0 40000f49  
3fffef70:  40000e19 40001878 00000004 00000000  
3fffef80:  3fffff10 aa55aa55 000000ed 40104424  
3fffef90:  4010442a 00000004 00000000 a9751f68  
3fffefa0:  4010000d e45c7604 ffd63db0 ca695611  
3fffefb0:  00000000 3fffef4c 00000000 3fffff08  
3fffefc0:  3fffffd0 00000000 00000000 feefeffe  
3fffefd0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffefe0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffeff0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff000:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff010:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff020:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff030:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff040:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff050:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff060:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff070:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff080:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff090:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff100:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff110:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff120:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff130:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff140:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff150:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff160:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff170:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff180:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff190:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff200:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff210:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff220:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff230:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff240:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff250:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff260:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff270:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff280:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff290:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff300:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff310:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff320:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff330:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff340:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff350:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff360:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff370:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff380:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff390:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff400:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff410:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff420:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff430:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff440:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff450:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff460:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff470:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff480:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff490:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff500:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff510:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff520:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff530:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff540:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff550:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff560:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff570:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff580:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff590:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff600:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff610:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff620:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff630:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff640:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff650:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff660:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff670:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff680:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff690:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff700:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff710:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff720:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff730:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff740:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff750:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff760:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff770:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff780:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff790:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff800:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff810:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff820:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff830:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff840:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff850:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff860:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff870:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff880:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff890:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff900:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff910:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff920:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff930:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff940:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff950:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff960:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff970:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff980:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff990:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa00:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa10:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa20:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa30:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa40:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa50:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa60:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa70:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa80:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa90:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffaa0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffab0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffac0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffad0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffae0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffaf0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb00:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb10:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb20:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb30:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb40:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb50:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb60:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb70:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb80:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb90:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffba0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbb0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbc0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbd0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbe0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbf0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc00:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc10:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc20:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc30:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc40:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc50:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc60:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc70:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc80:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc90:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffca0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffcb0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffcc0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffcd0:  feefeffe feefeffe 40227cb3 00000001  
3ffffce0:  ffffffff 00000000 3ffe96b1 00000008  
3ffffcf0:  40227d02 3ffeccf8 3ffefadc 00000001  
3ffffd00:  3fff07e8 00000000 4010106b 3ffeccf8  
3ffffd10:  000000c0 4021a0c2 00000008 3fff06d8  
3ffffd20:  40226d70 3ffeccf8 3ffed470 3fff07e8  
3ffffd30:  00000000 4021a22b 3ffefd84 feefeffe  
3ffffd40:  00000000 00000002 00000001 3ffeccf8  
3ffffd50:  00000000 400042db 3fff07e8 3ffeff44  
3ffffd60:  40004b31 3fff080c 0000049c 0007e000  
3ffffd70:  401057e0 4020dfcd 3ffef154 3ffeff44  
3ffffd80:  40106475 3fff080c 0000049c 00000000  
3ffffd90:  00000000 00000000 00000020 40100f22  
3ffffda0:  00000000 00000000 00000020 40100f22  
3ffffdb0:  3ffe9560 40104304 3fff0104 40100f22  
3ffffdc0:  00000001 40103523 3ffed6e0 40100f22  
3ffffdd0:  40103986 00000000 00000020 40100f22  
3ffffde0:  4010346a 0000007f 7fffffff 00000000  
3ffffdf0:  4010346a 0000007f 7fffffff 00000000  
3ffffe00:  0000007f 00040000 7fffffff 00000000  
3ffffe10:  40103269 00040000 7fffffff 00000000  
3ffffe20:  00000000 00000000 0000001f 40104bfd  
3ffffe30:  00000000 00000000 0000001f 40104bfd  
3ffffe40:  4000050c 00000030 00000011 ffffffff  
3ffffe50:  00000000 00000000 0000001f 40104bfd  
3ffffe60:  4000050c 00000002 03316038 00000000  
3ffffe70:  4020386b 00000030 00000010 ffffffff  
3ffffe80:  00000000 00000000 0000001f 40104bfd  
3ffffe90:  4000050c 00000000 00000000 fffffffe  
3ffffea0:  40000ea6 00000030 0000001e ffffffff  
3ffffeb0:  40000ea3 00000000 00000001 00000001  
3ffffec0:  3fffdab0 00000000 3fffd9d0 3ffeefec  
3ffffed0:  00000000 00000000 00000001 3ffeefe4  
3ffffee0:  00000000 3fffdad0 3ffeefec 00000030  
3ffffef0:  ffffffff 3fffc6fc 00000001 3ffe85e8  
3fffff00:  00000000 3fffdad0 3ffeefec 00000030  
3fffff10:  00000000 3fffdad0 3ffeefec 00000030  
3fffff20:  402077a4 3ffeedfc 000003e8 402074e2  
3fffff30:  3ffe8f00 00000000 00000000 40207525  
3fffff40:  3ffe8cac 3ffeedfc 3ffeee00 40203fbe  
3fffff50:  3fff014c 00ffffff 3ffeef2c 4020671c  
3fffff60:  3fffdad0 3ffeedfc 3ffeedfc 40207918  
3fffff70:  4020290c 00000000 3ffeedfc 40204f31  
3fffff80:  40207b28 00000000 00001388 40207c40  
3fffff90:  00000000 00000000 feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffffa0:  00000000 00000000 00000001 40207449  
<<<stack<<<

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,7)

wdt reset

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,7)

wdt reset
```

Could someone please tell me how can I make it work again?

Comment: If reflashing the code doesn't fix it, then it could be a hardware fault. Try another unit.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the sketch you posted and it works.

The most likely problem is the power source for the ESP8266. You have in the title ESP8266-1 so I will assume you have a ESP-01 module.

A lot of people who start with the ESP-01, or any other module without an onboard 3.3v regulator, don't know how demanding the ESP8266 is on the power source. It needs to have a stable 500mA capacity for it to work reliably. Also the regulator must be electrically close to the module. Using long connecting wires is one problem I see often.

The ESP8266 could have enough power to get programmed correctly but when it comes to transmitting it will draw a lot more current and if the power supply is insufficient a voltage dip occurs and then unpredictable behaviour occurs.

Check over any connections that might be poor. Please post what you are using for hardware if you can't get things running again.

Comment: note that AP mode uses more power than STA because sleep is disabled by default...